# How to get the last 7 days in c#

Tags: c#

I have this data on my database containing :

```
Id      FirstName          Date
1       Heru         2019-09-10 09:00:00.000
2       Angie        2019-09-10 09:00:00.000
3       Gel          2019-09-02 09:00:00.000
```

I wanted to get the last 7 days of it :

Here is my code :

```
var dateRange = new DateTimeFromTo();
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var allSalesPro = new List<SalesProStats>();

dateRange.From = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day).AddDays(-7);
dateRange.To = currentDate;
allSalesPro = AddSalesProToList(storeId, filter, dateRange);
```

My code works fine.

but there are instances that if my 
currentDate starts at 8:00:00

there will be no data to retrieve..

Many thanks! :)

Comment: What does `AddSalesProToList` do? Are you trying to return sales in the *future*? `From` doesn't have a time part and `To` should return any records up to the current time **if** the SQL query was a simple` BETWEEN @from and @to`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you filter on this period, in an exclusive manner. Like:

```
Date >= fromDate AND Date < toDate
```

In that case it's easier to represent the range of dates as following:

```
dateRange.From = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
dateRange.To = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
```

This way you completely bypass the time component because you are using complete dates. Also note that I'm using `DateTime.Today` instead of `.Now`, to avoid getting unnecessary times in my `DateTime` objects.

An alternative to this approach would be to rewrite your `AddSalesProToList` to rewrite your `toDate` parameter accordingly. This makes usage of the method easier because the developers need to think less about what they supply. I don't know if this is applicable to your situation, but I still wanted to point it out.

Comment: so if my currentDate is 2019-09-09 18:00:00

then the result of that will be

dateRange.From = 2019-09-03
dateRange.To = 2019-09-10 12:00:00

which is very confusing because my current date is today..
is there any other way?

aside from this :
dateRange.To = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 23, 59, 59);

Comment: `< 2019-09-10 12:00:00` means everything before the start of tomorrow. Which includes today. Definitely don't use your idea @BellmeeStore since it won't handle the time if it is 10 milliseconds before midnight, for example. While this answer (`< toDate`) **will** handle that.

Comment: @BellmeeStore welcome to the nightmare that is filtering by periods of dates and times. You have to be careful when doing this. First you have to ask yourself the question if the times of the dates are relevant. If not (and apparently you do not want them to be relevant) you have to take special care to eliminate them from the operands of your filter. The other thing to take note of, is the difference between and inclusive filter (smaller than or equal to) and an exclusive filter (smaller than).

Answer (score 1):

The response of **pyrocumulus** is OK, but this response gets 8 (`=  1 - (-7)`) days.

```
dateRange.From = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);
dateRange.To = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
```

There is today plus six days before.

Thanks

Comment: The alternative I offered does indeed, thanks for stating. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the date (as opposed to DateTime):

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Comment: Or `DateTime.Today`. That probably won't work either, as `From` is just a date already and `DateTime.Now` is later than `DateTime.Today`. Most likely there are dates in the future that the *query* can't cover

Answer (score -1):

To get the data from last 7 days including today try this,

```
var dateRange = new DateTimeFromTo();
dateRange.From = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
dateRange.To = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);

allSalesPro = AddSalesProToList(storeId, filter, dateRange);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);` to get the date correct without time. It all depends on your conditions, what are your operations? (<,>,=)